# PHP fwrite and sql query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, fwrite

Hello i am having a bit of trouble getting this code to work.

```
<?php
$filename = "test.php";
$filehandle = fopen($filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$test= 
    '
        $conn = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password" ) or die (mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_select_db("db", $conn);
        $query = "select * from test";
        $result =  mysql_query ($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

        echo $row[\'test\'];

    ';
fwrite($filehandle, $test);
fclose($filehandle);
?>
```

instead of outputting the results of the query it is outputting the query instead, I imagine this is because I am storing the full query in a variable, does anyone know how i will be able to output the results of the query instead of the actual query? Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Huh what? You're **not** storing the full query. You're storing PHP code in it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Since it's inside a single-quoted string, he needs to escape the quotes.

Comment: Does `test.php` already have `<?php` at the beginning of it? If not, you need to include it in `$test`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh? Do you have a link I can read up on? It's new to me. I always thought that double quotes needed escaping, but "singles"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Any quote needs escaping if it's inside a string started with the same quote. Otherwise it will end the string.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, it's good info to know; noted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe you missed the fact that this is part of a multi-line string started with `$test = '`

Comment: @Barmar Oohhh I see it now. Got it, 100% - and yes I did miss that. Much appreciated. I deleted my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should be using MySQLi or PDO

However your code should look something like this :

```
$filename = "test.php";
$filehandle = fopen( $filename ,'a' ) or die( "can't open file" );
$conn = mysql_connect( "server" ,"username" ,"password" ) or die ( mysql_error() ) ;
mysql_select_db( "db" ,$conn );
$query = "select * from test";
$result =  mysql_query( $query );
//  Iterate through results
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
{
//  var_dump[$row];
    //  Replace your-column-name below with the actual name :
    fwrite( $filehandle ,$row['your-column-name'] );
}
fclose( $filehandle );
```

Find some examples from manual pages : [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) , [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) , [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) .

Comment: Thanks for this it's like you just knew I planned on using a loop :).

Answer (score 1):

don't you think it should be something like:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password" ) or die (mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("db", $conn);
$query = "select * from test";
$result =  mysql_query ($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$test = $row['test'];
$filename = "test.php";
$filehandle = fopen($filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($filehandle, $test);
fclose($filehandle);
?>
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants. But anyway, you don't need to escape the single quotes in `$row`.

Comment: don't you think it should be something like: `$row['test'];`

Comment: Lol... I didn't even see what he wrote, just moved it out of the variabble $test...:P

Comment: @jphillip724 hope I helped... please select the answer using the check/tick button on the left to the post...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$filename = "test.php";
$filehandle = fopen($filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");

// do the query
$conn = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password" ) or die (mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("db", $conn);
$query = "select * from test";
$result =  mysql_query ($query);

// get the result row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

// write a field to file
fwrite($filehandle, $row['test']);
fclose($filehandle);
?>
```